# doctrine2 symfony2 relations entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a very big problem.

1 . I have a class User of FOS i have a form of register for Supervisors , the process of registration works very well.

2 . Every Supervisor has his Personals and he has also a Form of adding a personal , this form is like the registration of Supervisor and the add process is in the same class of Supervisor Class User .

--> so the Supervisor and his Personals there are in the same Class .

The Question Now :

When a Supervisor Login how i will select him his Personals and there are in the same Table ?

Suggestions :

**1 . I do a ManyToOne and OneToMany in the same class User with 2 attributes parent and childs like this :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Common\AuthenticationBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="parent")
 */
protected $childs;

public function __construct() {
    $this->childs = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Common\AuthenticationBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="childs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $parent;
```

I don't know how does it work this ?

**2 . I create another Class SupervisorPersonal where i put the supervisor_id and personal_id when the supervisor do the add a new personal.**

this also has a problem of mapping with Doctrine what's the relation between the 2 class and how Doctrine do the migration of the key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way of implementing this scenario would be to create a many to one relation on the User class. The many to one relation will represent many personal who belong to User class having relations to a single supervisor, which is again belongs to the same User class.

In yml config this can be represented as

```
manyToOne:
supervisor:
  targetEntity: Common\AuthenticationBundle\Entity\User
  joinColumn:
    name: supervisor_id
    referencedColumnName: id
```

And annotation

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Common\AuthenticationBundle\Entity\User")
 * @JoinColumn(name="supervisor_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $supervisor;
```

To get all the personals for a supervisor, you will have to write a repository function which takes the supervisorId as the parameter.

```
public function getAllPersonslsForSupervisor($supervisorId)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT e FROM AuthenticationBundle:User e
         WHERE e.supervisor = :supervisor")
            ->setParameter('supervisor', $supervisorId);

    $entities = $query->getResult();

    return $entities;
}
```

You may have to give the correct namespace for the entity in the query.

Comment: thank you plbit . the insertion works very well and in the the table the  column supervisor_id take the id of the supervisor . but now how to select all the personals when the supervisor wants to see his personals ?

Comment: I have modified the answer to include the repository function for fetching all the personals for a given supervisor id.